# setting usestate hook for the array to [] (empty array) doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, immutability

I'm trying to show products depends on the selected category tab. The **first tab** is 'show all' and its **categoryId =""** I change the categoryId when tab changes. I show products by using **shownMenuItems state** (shownMenuItems.map(...)), and get all items from api first in useEffect hook and store this data into **menuItems state**.

I need to set shownItems to an empty array before every tab changing. So I can get rid of previous tab's products. I used setShownMenuItems([]) but this doesn't work. Isn't it immutable operation? I create a new array and set it to shownMenuItems.

```
useEffect(() => {

      setShownMenuItems([])      //every time the tab changes, items will be shown is supposed to be cleared, and be filled after below conditions    

      if(categoryId===""){        //show all products tab's categoryId = ""
        setShownMenuItems(menuItems)          //sets shownMenuItems to all menu items
      }else{
        menuItems.forEach(menuItem=>{       
            if(menuItem.categoryId === categoryId){         //searches all menu items, looking for ones category id's match
                setShownMenuItems([...shownMenuItems, menuItem])
            }
        })
      }
      
  }, [categoryId])
```

I thought this part of code is enough. If it doesn't, tell me to share more codes. Thanks.

---

**Solution**:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setShownMenuItems([])      //every time the tab changes, items will be shown is supposed to be cleared, and be filled after below conditions    
      if(categoryId===""){        //show all products tab's categoryId = ""
        setShownMenuItems(menuItems)          //sets shownMenuItems to all menu items
      }else{
        menuItems.forEach(menuItem=>{       
            if(menuItem.categoryId === categoryId){         //searches all menu items, looking for ones category id's match
                // setShownMenuItems([...shownMenuItems, menuItem])
                setShownMenuItems(prev=>[...prev, menuItem])
            }
        })
      }
      
  }, [categoryId])
```

Comment: _I need to set shownItems to an empty array before every tab changing. So I can get rid of previous tab's products_ Why not setting the state to an entirely new array instead?

Answer (score 1):

React collect all set state hooks inside useEffect and apply them together. Split this logic to two useEffect.
Also, for prevent not necessary rerender You need to filter all items and only after that all of them set as new state.

```js
useEffect(() => {
setShownMenuItems([])      //every time the tab changes, items will be shown is supposed to be cleared, and be filled after below conditions    
}, [categoryId]) ;
useEffect(() => {
      if(categoryId===""){        //show all products tab's categoryId = ""
        setShownMenuItems(menuItems)          //sets shownMenuItems to all menu items
      } else{
        const filtered = menuItems.filter(menuItem => {
         return menuItem.categoryId === categoryId;
        });
        setShownMenuItems(filtered) ;
      }
      
  }, [categoryId])
```

Comment: it worked when I changed it over the previous version in a way I couldn't understand. I tried the setShownMenuItems([]) function in the same useEffect. It works both ways. (in the same useEffect and in two different useEffects)